# Assigning function to button in foreach loop causes all buttons to have the same argument value

Tags: unity, c#

I have a script that generates buttons based on a list of assets. Each button is intended to to add the asset's resource path to a variable called `SpawnGlobals.CurrentSelection`. When printing the asset resource name of all button within the loop, the different resoruce paths are shown. When printing the value in the select function, the value is always the last item in the `asset_register` list.

I do not understand why this is happening. Am I using the foreach loop or lambda incorrectly?

```
void Start () {

    //Add Foundry Assets Here:
    SpawnGlobals.asset_register.Add (new FoundryAsset ("Test Sphere", "sphere_obj"));
    SpawnGlobals.asset_register.Add (new FoundryAsset ("Building Block 10x10x10 01", "BuildingBlock10x10x10_01"));
    SpawnGlobals.asset_register.Add (new FoundryAsset ("Building Block 10x10x10 02", "BuildingBlock10x10x10_02"));
    SpawnGlobals.asset_register.Add (new FoundryAsset ("Building Block 10x10x10 03", "BuildingBlock10x10x10_03"));
    foreach (FoundryAsset asset in SpawnGlobals.asset_register) {
        SpawnGlobals.buttons.Add(Instantiate(button_prefab));
        GameObject current_button = SpawnGlobals.buttons.Last ();
        current_button.transform.SetParent(master.transform, false);

        current_button.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = asset.AssetName;

        print (asset.AssetName);
        current_button.GetComponentInChildren<Button>().onClick.AddListener (delegate {
            select(asset.ResourcePath);
        });

    }


}
public void select(string selected)
{
    print (selected);
    SpawnGlobals.CurrentSelection = selected;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem does lie in your use of the lambda. Specifically, you're capturing the foreach iteration variable, which is of a reference type. The value pointed to by that reference changes as the loop iterates, but the capture is still of that variable, which means when the lambdas are eventually invoked they are all referring to the same asset (the one that happened to be last in the iteration).

[In other words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168375/using-the-iterator-variable-of-foreach-loop-in-a-lambda-expression-why-fails) it's the variable that is captured, not the value.

You can fix this simply by capturing a local variable in the loop instead:

```
foreach (FoundryAsset asset in SpawnGlobals.asset_register) {
   FoundryAsset captured = asset;
   ...
   current_button.GetComponentInChildren<Button>().onClick.AddListener (delegate {
        select(captured .ResourcePath);
    });
}
```

(Note that this behavior changes in a later version of C#, but that Unity does not support that version.)